# R language: open ssh connection

Tags: r, networking, ssh

I am trying to open a remote shell via ssh to send commands from R.
As long as I send commands, I need to get results and send new commands that depends on the output of the previous ones.

For this reason I am looking for a solution to open a connection and manage it from within the R code until I have finished. I also need to open the connection with ssh key exchange (so without password authentication).

Looking at CRAN I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If it is running R code on a server, solutions like `Rserve` allow you to do just that.

Comment: Would `system` or `shell` cut it?

Comment: I need to launch some commands and capture the output on a remote machine connecting with ssh. My R program is on a local pc.

I investigated system() and shell() but, as far as I understood, you cannot interact with the remote shell without opening and closing the ssh connection for each invocation of system().

Comment: My question comes from the need to run some R code after the invocation of each command at the remote machine. I would like to avoid opening and closing the ssh connection each time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider CRAN packages:

- [ssh.utils](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh.utils/index.html)
- [RCurl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html)

**RCurl** supports [scp](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rcurl/docs/scp)

**ssh.utils** supports also remote execution and monitoring:

https://github.com/collectivemedia/ssh.utils/tree/master/man